# JEE 7 Scheduler how to fork a task without blocking the scheduler

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, task, scheduler

In a JEE 7 WildFly environment I want to execute a task (a method of a worker class) **without blocking the scheduler**.
So that the scheduler is able to start multiple "tasks/threads" which are running independently from the scheduler (fire and forget).

In plain old Java I only have to start a new Thread, but in a managed container this is forbidden.

**How can I attain this?**

This is a short primitive example (which is **not working**) to clarify what I want to do:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class MyScheduler {

    public static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(MyScheduler.class);

    private int counter = 0;

    @Schedule(second = "*/5", minute = "*", hour = "*", persistent = false)
    public void atSchedule() throws InterruptedException {

        LOGGER.info("{}. scheduler call - every five secs.", (++counter));

        final Worker worker = new Worker(counter);
        worker.doSomethingWithoutBlocking();

        LOGGER.info("Scheduler done.");

    }   

} // class MyScheduler 


@Stateless
@Asynchronous
public class Worker {

    public static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Worker.class);

    private int nr; 

    public Worker() {}

    public Worker(final int nr) {
        this.nr = nr;
    }

    @Asynchronous
    public void doSomethingWithoutBlocking() {

        for(long i = 0; i < 10000000000L; i++) {

            if(i % 1000000000 == 0) {
                LOGGER.info("{}. Worker: i = {}", nr, i);
            } // if

        } // for

    }


} // class Worker
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you use ManagedExecutorService, which is provided by the application server. Given that you don't need the Worker class to be an EJB, the below given code should do the trick. I haven't tried to run it on Wildfly, but verified on Payara Server.

```
@Singleton
public class Scheduler {
    private int counter = 0;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Scheduler.class.getName());

    @Resource
    ManagedExecutorService mes;

    @Schedule(second = "*/5", minute = "*", hour = "*", persistent = false)
    public void atSchedule() throws InterruptedException {
        LOGGER.info(String.format("%d. scheduler call - every five secs.", (++counter)));
        mes.submit(() -> {
            final Worker worker = new Worker(counter);
            worker.doSomething();
        });

        LOGGER.info("Scheduler done.");

    }   
}

public class Worker {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Worker.class.getName());
    private int nr; 

    public Worker() {}

    public Worker(final int nr) {
        this.nr = nr;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        for(long i = 0; i < 10000000000L; i++) {
            if(i % 1000000000 == 0) {
                LOGGER.info(String.format("%d. Worker: i = %d", nr, i));
            } // if
        } // for
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think that this is the best idea, but:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class MyScheduler {

   public static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(MyScheduler.class);

private int counter = 0;


@Schedule(second = "*/5", minute = "*", hour = "*", persistent = false)
public void atSchedule() throws InterruptedException {

    LOGGER.info("{}. scheduler call - every five secs.", (++counter));
    final Worker worker = new Worker(counter);
    runWithoutBlocking(worker);
    LOGGER.info("Scheduler done.");
}

@Async
void runWithoutBlocking(Worker worker) {
    worker.doSomethingWithoutBlocking();
}
```

}